# What router bits do I need for this job?

Tags: router, router-bit

I live in a 1930s house in the UK with all the original windows (single glazed). All the windows are wooden casements (although a few are "faux casements": they look like real opening casements next to them, but in fact don't open).

I'm planning to replace all panes with vacuum-glazing (a form of double glazing) panes and also add some bulb weatherstrip in a groove to help with both noise and heat insulation. A first set of vacuum panes are on order and will be delivered in March.

I've bought a router ([Makita RT0700CX4](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Makita-RT0700CX4-240-Router-Trimmer/dp/B00EKK6LAO/ref=sr_1_5?crid=12H7UBGSQ41NY&keywords=makita%2Brouter%2Brt0700C&qid=1675081609&sprefix=makita%2520router%2520rt0700c%2Caps%2C83&sr=8-5&th=1), 710W) and am a total newb when it comes to routers.

**1. Cutting a very narrow groove for bulb weatherstrip**

The weatherstrip grooves (to be cut on the side of the frames, obviously) need to be about 3 mm wide. I *think* the recommended thing here is something like [this](https://www.wealdentool.com/acatalog/Compression-1-Flute.html#aTGC041540). But I'm also aware of these "groover" bits, such as [this](https://www.wealdentool.com/acatalog/Online_Catalogue_3_0mm_Groover_305.html). In the latter case I believe the router would be moved along the top of the window, with the cutting blade cutting into the edge. Which type should I use?

**2. Machining the rabbets on the frames to accommodate the new panes**

The thickness of the existing glazing is probably about 3 mm. The vacuum glazing panes will be 8.3 mm thick.

This means that the rabbets on the outside of the casement frames will have to be made deeper. But the area in which the new panes will sit will probably also be slightly wider, because the edge beyond the sight lines of the new panes is 10 mm all round (NB inevitably these panes are much heavier than the existing ones).

So what sort of router bit should I looking at in order to both deepen and widen the rabbet groove holding the panes in the casement frames?

Hope all the above makes sense...

***Edit***

Following the comment by FreeMan I contacted Makita UK. Just a note therefore about the shank gauges on bits used with this router. According to the Makita UK technician you should use **Imperial diameter bits** with this router (1/4" or 3/8"), despite what it appears to say in the manual. Pretty important.

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  Your question could really benefit from a sketch of the cross section you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi and welcome. *"and am a total newb when it comes to routers"* Well pause right now. I have three tips. 1, before you even touch a piece of wood (especially one from your windows!) with a bit, familiarise yourself with all aspects of router safety. Headsup, this should be a multi-day thing, don't expect to be up to speed in just an hour of online searching. 2nd, do numerous practice runs on scrap wood before you commit with any of your precious window pieces! 3rd, I don't think this is optional, I think you're going to **need** a router table. Don't despair about added cost [contd]

Comment: ....you can make a bare-bones router 'table' for almost nothing and it'll be perfectly adequate for what you require. This can be nothing more than a sheet of plywood or MDF with a hole in it, and one straight piece of wood or metal as the fence. As ridiculous as this might sound this can do all that many users require for an amazing amount of time (no joke, some pros used a setup like this for *years* in a professional setting).

Comment: @Graphus Thanks, you're talking my language. I said exactly that about extreme respect for this new item (safety) in a comment on bowlturner's answer. And about experimenting on waste wood. I have already started watching vids on "beginner router user". This is a very frightening piece of kit. Have seen a couple of vids already about making a basic table/jig, so will follow that recommendation.

Comment: perhaps this is the sort of thing you have in mind: https://www.reddit.com/r/woodworking/comments/10nsdrh/portable_plywood_router_table_and_the_fence_i/ ... i.e. the router is permanently attached to its "table" and never gets to "float free". Any other vids or guides online you'd recommend?

Comment: Also, be _very_ sure that you get the correct size shank for your router. That Amazon link indicates that the router uses "metric measurements", so that _most likely_ means that it takes a 6mm shank bit. Be _very_ aware that many bits (though fewer in the UK) are sold with a 1/4" shank. That 0.4 mm difference in diameter between 6mm and 1/4" can lead to damaging your router or worse, damaging _you_.

Comment: @FreeMan interesting point: in the details at the Amazon page it says "Collet capacity 6mm and 8mm (1/4”)". In the manual it says "Collet chuck capacity: 6 mm, 8 mm, 1/4" or 3/8"".

Comment: Hrm... Generally speaking 6mm & 1/4 do _not_ mix. You don't want that little hunk of sharp, spinning metal coming loose at 20k RPM! It might be that the manual is multinational and yours is a 6mm, while mine (in the US) would be 1/4"... Honestly, I don't know on that one - I'd strongly recommend contacting Makita at their most local to you contact and asking specifically. Some routers come with multiple collets and you simply swap collet to use a bit with a different shank size. Maybe look in the box for different parts.

Comment: @FreeMan I will now get clarification direct from Makita in view of your comments. I had a look in the box and also a thorough look through the manual. Nothing relating to this issue (or any suggestions of multiple collets).

Comment: Mike, instead of relying only on online content (I mean stuff made for the Internet, since I am about to recommend something online LOL) this is something you want to hit the books for IMO. As much respect as I have for some teachers like James on StumpyNubs (if you haven't seen this channel already, I highly highly recommend it) there are certain things books tend to cover a little better, include details often not seen in videos. Anyway head on over to Archive.org and start with **Router Basics** by Patrick Spielman. Also look for titles by Jim Phillips and Nick Engler. All are free to read.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks again. Once again, I seem to be doing the right thing so far: 3 days ago I ordered a book, "Working with the Router" by Hylton. I agree about books. Will check out those online leads.

Comment: @FreeMan Just heard back from Makita UK: the technician said "use Imperial" and said it shouldn't really suggest metric gauge shanks for the bits. Nice to know (!).

Answer (score 2):

If I had more pictures to make sure I'm envisioning correctly all the parts you are discussing I'd have a little more confidence in this answer.  But here it goes.

Routers are the easiest way to totally hose up a project if care isn't taken.  you need guides or fences to reduce wiggle, wobble and slips.

I am assuming you will be taking the frames apart to do this because if you don't you'll have to use a chisel or something similar to take care of all the corners (for the panes, not the weather striping).

I personally would tend to use a groover style bit, if it can make the groove deep enough for your project because you have one flat guide surface built into it. And if you have the right size guide bearing, it's fairly 'easy' to do it right.

If you have a router table (and you can make a simple one from a piece of plywood and 2x4's ) then you can use the straight bit and a fence. Which can be very fast and easy, once set up.

In either case, I'd have some test pieces to play with to make sure you get all your settings correct before trying it out on your actual windows.

One last thing make sure all your pieces are marked inside/outside so that you run them all through facing the same direction.  Because no matter how close to 'centered' you are, you aren't.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. From initial reading I already have a very healthy respect for this new piece of kit: safety, "run-away router", etc.  Re (inner) corners: it had occurred to me that this would be tricky: rather than disassembling the casement frames I'd assumed I'd have to do that by hand or with a Dremel-style detail tool: have some wood carving skills and tools. I have til mid-March to experiment on bits of waste wood before I'll be doing anything for real.  Tx for the table recommendation. Any specific recommendation re the type of bit to expand the rabbets?

Comment: @mikerodent for the rabbets, especially if you aren't taking them apart, I'd us a 'groove' style bit, it doesn't have to be the same width as the finished rabbet, you can set the 'height' to widen 1 side and/or the other individually, running the bit around the inside.  Makes sense what I'm trying to say?

Comment: yes, lot of sense, thanks.

Comment: "'groove' _stile_ bit" or "'groove' _style_ bit"? There's a difference...

Comment: @FreeMan I can't spell.

Comment: Happens to the best of us...